# Why does my register user post request fail with a 500 error?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building an app with React and Node/Express, and I'm having trouble with my register user function. The data I am passing in is correct, and other endpoints work fine. The register one keeps returning a 500 error and I can't figure out why.

This is my request:

```
   console.log(values)
  axios
    .post(
      'https://foodtrackr-backend.herokuapp.com/api/register',
      values
    )
    .then(res => {
      console.log('res.data', res.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('nope');
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

and this is my endpoint:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  let user = req.body;
  const newUser = await Users.add(user);
  try {
    if (newUser) {
      res.status(201).json(user);
    } else res.status(404);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json('noooooo');
  }
});
```

and this is my model:

```
function findById(id) {
  return (
    db('users')
      .where({ id })
      .first()
  );
}

async function add(user) {
  const [id] = await db('users').insert(user, 'id');
  return findById(id);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the error if you do `console.log(error)` before `res.status(500)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Turns out the error was in the way I formatted my server.use when specifying my routers in the server.js file. All is well!

Comment: console.log() everything :)